Customizing Ticks For com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
I have a com.google.android.material.slider.Slider for which I would like to customize the thumb & ticks. I have managed most of the thumb using app:thumbRadius & the SetCustomThumbDrawable method. However, all I have been able to do for the ticks are set a radius & color. This just creates circles along the track, which I find pretty useless to the user since they have no idea what value they are selecting (sure, the label is displayed while sliding the thumb, but sometimes that is covered by the user's finger, so they never see it anyway). I would like my ticks to be vertical lines with a labels below them. Is there a way to use a Drawable for the ticks? Is there any way to display values matching the ticks? Is there an alternative to com.google.android.material.slider.Slider that is more customizable?
